# FILTER on REGEXMATCH on Google Sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet. One column in the sheet lists tags for the rows. Each row in the sheet will have one or more tags.

I want to filter the spreadsheet to match on specific a tag whilst excluding matches that also contain another specific tag.

So the sake of simplicity, lets say I want to match all rows that contain the tag BREAD in the column I, but not those that contain the tag MILK, even if that row also contains the tag for BREAD.

I have used the formula below, but it doesn't work. In fact it results in an google sheet error.

```
FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, "BREAD|^(?!.*MILK).*$")
```

I do know the formula works when I omit the negative lookahead.

```
FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, "BREAD")
```

So
1.Can this be done on google sheets ?
2. If so, how ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the flavor of regex that Google Sheets uses (RE2) doesn't support lookaround. https://github.com/google/re2/issues/156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Documentation for Filter is here:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?sjid=11303190860980604116-AP

Why not utilise the mutliple conditions of the function?

```
=FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, "BREAD"), NOT(REGEXMATCH(I2:P, "Milk")))
```

Note the `NOT()` function.

Could substitute REGEXMATCH for `Find` (case sensitive) or `Search` (ignores case) which would likely be more performant.

```
 =FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, "BREAD"), IFERROR(NOT(FIND("Milk", I2:P)), FALSE()))
```

Find: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en&sjid=11303190860980604116-AP

```
=FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, "BREAD"), NOT(IFERROR(SEARCH(I2:P, "Milk")), FALSE()))
```

Search: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en&sjid=11303190860980604116-AP

Not tested.